# Touch screen issue on Ubuntu 22.04 desktop edition on my Lenovo Flex 5

Tags: ubuntu, touchscreen

I installed Ubuntu desktop on my Lenovo flex 5 but it doesn't even identify my touch screen. I even checked with the command **xinput list** but this is all it outputs

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Can I please get help regarding this?
Thanks!

I tried running **xinput list** to see if it recognizes my touch screen but it doesn't

Comment: Better try [ubuntu.se]